# I am not able start chef on cygwin

Tags: ruby, linux, cygwin, chef-infra

My platform is windows. I installed chef development kill using chefdk-0.19.6-1-x86.msi.

Then using Cygwin executed the below command

```
echo 'eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

to set chef ruby as default

I don't have ruby

```
 $ which ruby
 which: no ruby in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl/site/bin:/cygdrive/c/Perl/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/1E/NomadBranch:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Application Virtualization Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Solidcore/Tools/GatherInfo:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Solidcore/Tools/Scanalyzer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Solidcore:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Solidcore/Tools/ScGetCerts:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Tools/GatherInfo:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Tools/Scanalyzer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/McAfee/Tools/ScGetCerts:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLI:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/bin:/home/JBE624/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin:/home/JBE624/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin)
```

But when I am trying to chef it is showing as below can anyone help

```
$ chef
C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef (LoadError)
```

I also tried below

```
 $ echo 'export PATH="/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef (LoadError)

followed below links

https://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html

Can anyone help me to solve the above error. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use cygwin here ? just get rid of it and use the same command `chef shell-init bash` in a dos prompt and you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

I use a number of alias entries in my `.bash_profile` to make it work in Cygwin.

```
alias knife='/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife'
alias chef-client='/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-client'
alias chef-solo='/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-solo'
alias shef='/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/shef'
alias chef='/cygdrive/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of stating it, we don't test our Windows packages on Cygwin nor do we encourage use with Cygwin. If you want bash because lolpowershell, just use a copy compiled for Windows natively. I usually use the one that comes with msysgit but there are plenty of builds elsewhere too.